# Linker error: cannot include httpClient - cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: c++, networking, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cocos2d::network::HttpClient *

I am trying to make network call from **cocos2d-x 3.2** and I am getting above error while compiling
I have included the file

> include "network/HttpClient.h"

and I am getting error at

> cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved

> right click on your project->add->references

add libnetwork from list.